# Creating a record table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

How can I create a record table when a client adds a new row on a table, which keeps ;

- the client's Id,
- when the data is added,
- Id of the data.

For example I have a PersonTable in mysql; and when a client(with the Id of 2 in users table) adds a new person with the Id of 12, my record table automatically adds cliend_id(2),related_Id(12) and creation time of the new record.

I think there is a way in mysql, writing a trigger would be possible, but is there any possible ways. I'm very beginner of mysql. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version you run of MySQL but from version 5.5 onwards this is possible when using TIMESTAMP as a type. Versions >=5.6.5 supports this functionality for type DATETIME as well.

```
-- TIMESTAMP example with 1 column
CREATE TABLE foo (
  'current_ts' TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

-- DATETIME example with 2 columns
CREATE TABLE foo (
    'creation_time'     DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    'modification_time' DATETIME ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

From the docs:

> As of MySQL 5.6.5, TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns can be automatically
>   initializated and updated to the current date and time (that is, the
>   current timestamp). Before 5.6.5, this is true only for TIMESTAMP, and
>   for at most one TIMESTAMP column per table. The following notes first
>   describe automatic initialization and updating for MySQL 5.6.5 and up,
>   then the differences for versions preceding 5.6.5.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html